# How do you update a field in postgres

Tags: postgresql, set, sql-update

I have a table named product.template, I want to change the values of the column christian (character varying) to product when I do :

```
UPDATE product_template SET christian = product;
```

I get an error saying :

```
ERROR:  column "product" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE product_template SET christian = product
                                                ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "product" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 41
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `product`? A column in another table or a string literal value?

Comment: Sorry, it is a string, it is the value I want to give to all the rows in the christian column !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value you want to update the column with is a string you have to quote it, so try this:

```
UPDATE product_template SET christian = 'product';
```

Comment: It worked, thanx, my mistake is that I had forgot to hit refresh in pgadmin 3 before doing the query. Since the field is name "type" (not my choice) and that it is a "reserved word" I renamed it to christian so I could do the changes.